# In CakePhP 3.0 what's the preferred way to search a MySQL DB on a unique index other than the primary key?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm assuming that in the simple get() in the following example $accountName has to be the value of a row's primary key, otherwise how does it even know which key, index or column you're trying to search on.

```
$myAccount = TableRegistry::get('Accounts')->get($accountName);
```

So supposing I want to search on some other unique index.  In my case it happens to be just a varchar column.  And I want the result to get loaded up into the class that got set up in Model/Entity/Account.php, in my case its the Account class.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to retrieve data using CakePHP.

In the one you mention:

```
TableRegistry::get('MyTable')->get($someValue);
```

`$someValue` is the primary key, named `id` if you have followed conventions.

To quickly retrieve records by other columns other than the primary key, you may want to use [Dynamic Finders](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders). To grasp an understanding how powerful these dynamically constructed methods are, you can do things such as:

```
TableRegistry::get('Users')->findByUsername('joebob');
TableRegistry::get('Users')->findAllByUsername('joebob');
TableRegistry::get('Users')->findAllByUsernameOrEmail('joebob', 'joe@example.com');
```

These examples have been taken from the docs. For more interesting stuff, I recommend that you take a look at the [Retrieving Data & Results Sets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html) section of the Cookbook.

---

Following your edit, to retrieve an account by its name, you can perform:

```
$query = $this->Account->findByName($accountName);
```

Provided the name of the account is stored in a field named `name`.

Comment: The cookbook always leaves me with more questions than anwers.  Well I have a column called "contact_info".  Does that mean there's a dynamic query: TableRegistry::get('Users')->findByContactInfo($thisContactInfo); that I could use?

Comment: That's correct. The dynamic method uses a [camelized](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#creating-camelcase-and-under-scored-forms) version of the field name.

Comment: it's probably my fault because I edited the question later.  The find returns a query that you then convert to an array for each row.  It's not like the "get" that gets you a that class that Model/Entity, correct?  So there's nothing more like get for a non-primary key?

Comment: I realize it can be a bit confusing. `get()` fetches a single `Entity` by primary key. Finder methods always return a `Query` object. Iteration of query objects returns entities. `$query->all()` returns a `ResultSet`. `$query->first()` returns an `Entity`. The [Database Access & ORM](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html) is what you need to go through for a better understanding of the 3.x ORM.